# How to replace a value of the element in soap request in Api Connect using Gateway scripting

Tags: javascript, api-gateway, apiconnect, ibm-api-connect, palantir-for-ibm-cloudpak-for-data

Below is input request that I have saved in the **Request** variable and saved the response string in the **ResponseString** variable. Now I need to replace the **ResponseString** variable value with **Payload** element value in the input request, please refer to the below request for reference. All helps are much appreciated!

var Request = apim.getvariable('originalRequest');

var ResponseString = 'DataIndex_12345';

Input Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:or="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <or:Request>
         <Sender>Mark</Sender>
         <Receiver>Steve</Receiver>
         <Payload>Data</Payload>
      </or:Request>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Expected Output Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:or="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <or:Request>
         <Sender>Mark</Sender>
         <Receiver>Steve</Receiver>
         <Payload>DataIndex_12345</Payload>
      </or:Request>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```